# Placement of a container using webkit-boxing-sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a new homepage based off of this page: http://www.blacktie.co/demo/shield/

Rather than just copy and replace text, I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS by re-creating pieces and learning how different parts impact each other.

The one part I am stuck at is trying to emulate how the greywrap (second container) pushes up to the headerwrap (the first background image on the main screen). After playing around with it, I found the following in bootstrap.css seems to control that portion since removing it breaks the style:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I learned the asterisk is the universal selector so it applies to all styles. I added that to my page.css.scss, I'm using bootstrap-sass, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Could someone guide me here or show me what I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: i don't understand what you want to emulate that #greywrap is doing. that's just a div with a grey background

Comment: I want to emulate that that the 'container' is pushing up against the background image above in the browser. Currently, my layout just stretches the image to the length of the page and I want it to be limited.

Comment: I just made the width smaller for the image so it didn't fit the screen. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

box-sizing doesn`t affect the placement of an object.

box-sizing: border-box includes the padding INSIDE the declared width/height:

Eg:

```
div { height: 100px; padding: 10px; } /* total height: 120px (100 + 10 + 10) */
div { height: 100px; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box } /* total height: 100px (100px height with an INSIDE padding of 10px;) */
```

Comment: Would this height be the height of the image? I just want to limit the length so it shows a peak of the second container just like it does in the demo of it.